# What KDE Konqueror plugin is this "display module for comic book"?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plugins

I have a Konqueror plugin, which is only used in very weird situations, due to a bug. However, I think it is a great plugin. However, I have no idea how to use it normally. The plugin lets me view the images of a folder like PDF pages. I just had this plugin active and I used the moment to make a screen shot of the name:

[image]

The text translates to "display module for comic book".

I am not able to find this plugin anywhere in the internet. The system I am running is Kubuntu 14.04, which is not supported anymore. Thus, I want to move to Kubuntu 20.04 soon. However, as long as I don't know what this plugin is called I a cannot look for it for the current Kubuntu / Qt.

Where can I find this and how can I use it (deliberately) for Kubuntu 20.04?

Comment: What OS/release are you using?  That looks like Kubuntu 14.04 LTS (and Qt4 which is EOL and removed from 20.04)

Comment: @guiverc: That is correct. I still want to know what the name of the plugin is and how to use it. I might find it also for Qt5 once I get to install a the current LTS.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  (*note: you shouldn't need the EOL upgrades link for 14.04 due to ESM availability for the release*)

Comment: @guiverc: Ok, I understand. I rephrased my question, now it should be on-topic, right?

Answer (score 1):

It is part of Okular Comic Book format generator.

Check the search [results on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=tobias+koenig+comic+book+format&type=Code).

On old systems it was provided by `okular` and `okular-kde4` packages.

On modern systems by the [`okular`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=okularGenerator_comicbook.so&searchon=contents) package.